# Vuex: why does my mutation commit call fail?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

My button triggers a `store commit` that calls a mutation. Super simple code, yet I get "cannot read property 'commit' of undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Note: my store information is contained in a separate file, but I get the same issue anyway when I don't do that.

**components/App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="viewNextWeek">button</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "TimeLOG"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    viewNextWeek: function() {
      this.$store.commit('nextWeek');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

**src/store/index.js containing store information:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    today: new Date(),
  },
  mutations: {
    nextWeek() {
      alert('test');
    }
  }
});
```

**src/main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import store from './store';

import App from './components/App.vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the `store` option in the root component to "inject" the store into all child components, see [getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components); In the `main.js`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```